# MATLAB: FREQZ plot

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, frequency, magnitude

The following code plots the frequency response of 2 systems.
However, the second phase plot is not showing on the plot.

```
freqz(X)
hold on
freqz(y)
lines = findall(gcf,'type','line');
lines(1).Color = 'red'
lines(2).Color = 'green'
lines(3).Color = 'red'
lines(4).Color = 'green'
```

[image]

How do i add the second phase plot onto the graph?

Comment: The answer has been found and will be shortly posted.